# Documented Web Site Design Process

Tags: web-development, website-design

Is there any well documented process to be used in web site design projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kelly Goto and Emily Cotler's [Web ReDesign](http://www.web-redesign.com/)(2004) will be showing some age by now if you pay too much attention to technical specifics, but its primary subjects are really workflow and process rather than code, so it might be worth a look. You can probably get a used copy pretty cheap with a little digging.

Comment: Thank you very much. This book provides very concrete and detailed process documentation for web site development projects.

Answer (score 2):

As the web design industry is fairly young the process hasn't crystallised into anything that you'd call "well documented". [This article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/22/following-a-web-design-process/) has a very useful process and links to other processes though.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely everyone does it different (or they should).
My workflow will be different than yours, and yours will be different than "That Guy".

With that said, I highly agree with paulmorriss above.
Most articles posted at SmashingMagazine are very informative and full of other resources.

One of my favorite new sites is: http://freelanceswitch.com/